# Install4J failed to delete file: Show filename in error message

Tags: install4j

If Install4J could not delete a file, a message is shown which says:

com.install4j...DeleteFileAction failed

Is there any way to show the path to the file which could not be deleted in the error message? Like a variable which i can use in the custom error description?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487880/can-i-pass-the-filespec-to-an-error-message-in-the-delete-files-and-directories?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detailed error messages are in the installation log file (.install4j/installation.log).